# Unable to update attributes of federated id's from cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-cli

I am using the federated id for creating users in Cognito with the google sign-in. Once users are created in Cognito. I need to get and update the phone number to Cognito.

I have tried the following command to do the same, this command works fine for other id's but for federated ids, I am facing an error.

I am trying to update from CLI

```
aws cognito-idp admin-update-user-attributes --user-pool-id XXX --username XXX@gmail.com --user-attributes Name="phone_number",Value="XXX"
```

Above command is working fine for other users but for federated ids I am getting "An error occurred (UserNotFoundException) when calling the AdminUpdateUserAttributes operation: User does not exist." issue even if the user exists already in the pool.

Is there any other way to update the phone numbers for federated ids?

Comment: are you sure you have the correct username? Did you grab it from the console?

Comment: Yes, username is correct. The same is true for update/delete/get of user's who are created by federated logins. Only those which are not present under user groups are getting listed/affected.